# Devise: Email has already been taken but user deleted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am using Devise for my user models and I've deleted a user from my admin panel, and confirmed that the user is no longer in the DB using `rails console`.  However, when I try to re-create the user (they want to sign up again), I'm presented with a flash error message:

> User failed to be created
>
> - Email has already been taken

Checking the DB again, the user still isn't there:

```
irb(main):007:0> User.find_by(email: 'user@example.com')
=> nil
```

Why is this happening and what can I do to fix this?  Does Devise keep a ghosted user somewhere that I'm not aware of?

Thanks,
Justin

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out, someone had installed the Paranoia gem.  So I had to find the user:

```
User.with_deleted.where(email: "user@example.com")
```

to get the id, then restore:

```
User.restore(the_id)
```